# Mysql join with latest update in 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Hi here is my tables..

Table Sites

```
     sid  sname       uid
    ----  ----------  ----
       1  aaa.com      1
       5  bbb.com      1
```

Table keywords_s

```
     kid  skeywoird       
    ----  ----------  
       1  word1    
       2  word2
```

Table matchon

```
mid    uid    sid     kid       
----  ------  -----  -----
   1    1        1     1      
   2    1        1     2
```

Table rank

```
 mid   rank    dateon           url       
----  ------   -------         -----
   2     7    08-May-2014      bbb.com/a
   2     6    09-May-2014      bbb.com/2
```

And my query

```
"SELECT 
    keywords_s.skeyword,
    keywords_s.kid,
    sites.sname,
    rank.rank,
    rank.url,
    rank.dateon
    FROM matchon
    Inner JOIN sites ON sites.sid = matchon.sid
    Inner JOIN keywords_s ON keywords_s.kid = matchon.kid
    Inner JOIN rank ON rank.mid = matchon.mid
    where matchon.uid = :uid and sites.sname = :sname and sites.deactive != '1'
    group by keywords_s.skeyword order by rank.rank
    "
```

I am getting output

```
rank   keyword    dateon        url       
----  ---------   -------      -----
   7   word2    08-May-2014    bbb.com/a
```

Output needed is

```
rank   keyword    dateon        url       
----  ---------   -------      -----
   6   word2    09-May-2014    bbb.com/2
```

Here what i want to get ...

1st Group by keywords_s.skeyword order by rank.rank (this is coming But)

2nd Order by rank.slno desc (not working)

(I need 2nd order to work so i can get latest rank and date with, group by skeyword and order by rank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT keywords_s.skeywor
     , keywords_s.kid
     , sites.sname
     , rank.rank
     , rank.url
     , rank.dateon
FROM matchon JOIN sites ON sites.sid = matchon.sid
             JOIN keywords_s ON keywords_s.kid = matchon.kid
             JOIN rank ON rank.mid = matchon.mid AND
                          rank.dateon = (SELECT MAX(dateon) FROM rank WHERE mid =  matchon.mid)
WHERE matchon.uid = :uid and sites.sname = :sname and sites.deactive != '1'
GROUP BY keywords_s.skeyword order by rank.rank
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as per your requirement

> `"Select * from(SELECT 
>       keywords_s.skeyword,
>       keywords_s.kid,
>       sites.sname,
>       rank.rank,
>       rank.url,
>       rank.dateon
>       FROM matchon
>       Inner JOIN sites ON sites.sid = matchon.sid
>       Inner JOIN keywords_s ON keywords_s.kid = matchon.kid
>       Inner JOIN rank ON rank.mid = matchon.mid
>       where matchon.uid = :uid and sites.sname = :sname and sites.deactive != '1'
>       order by rank.rank desc)xyz
>       group by xyz.skeyword
>       "`